# Locust - get stats in python

Tags: python, locust

How does one get the Locust stats inside python? I'm trying to get the current value of req/s but locust.env.Environment.stats is an empty object, and locust.stats.print_stats() needs a callable object, and I don't know what to pass to it.

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to access the environment?